# JPA keeps thowing "Object: entities.Json[ id=null ] is not a known Entity type."

Tags: java, mysql, jpa-2.0

**UPDATE**
I seems that if I add a timestamp it caused the problems but I have no idea why. I tried some advice but unfortunately it didn't work

```
@Basic(optional = true)
@NotNull
@Column(name="created", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created;
```

**UPDATE #2**

This is the worst outcome: The issue is fixed but I don't know why! I changed the entity class to:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name="created", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created;
```

and it still didn't work. I restarted glassfish, it still didn't work. I went to a meeting, restarted it again and **IT WORKED** I am very annoyed as I learn nothing and lost hours on something that should have taken 30 seconds.

I was editing the project on Netbeans in debug mode so I expected all my changes to be redeployed on file save. If this is not the case maybe you could shed some light.

I also tried to setup *org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence* but I just gave up... for now :)

**--------------------------------------------------------------------**

**TL;DR**

I have struggled with this for hours and read all the posts I could find on SOF.

I have ended up decimating my table in my efforts to get this to work and although I have defined an auto-incremental primary id I get a

*Object: entities.Json[ id=null ] is not a known Entity type.*

error and if I set the value I get a

*Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.*

error.

**MySQL Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `evaluationdb`.`json` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`ref_id` INT NOT NULL , 
`json` VARCHAR(4096) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
`created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) 
ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

**Entitiy**

```
package entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "json")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Json.findAll", query = "SELECT j FROM Json j")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Json.findById", query = "SELECT j FROM Json j WHERE j.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Json.findByRefid", query = "SELECT j FROM Json j WHERE j.refid = :refid")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Json.findByJson", query = "SELECT j FROM Json j WHERE j.json = :json")})
public class Json implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "refid")
    private int refid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 4096)
    @Column(name = "json")
    private String json;

    public Json() {
    }

    public Json(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Json(Integer id, int refid, String json) {
        this.id = id;
        this.refid = refid;
        this.json = json;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getRefid() {
        return refid;
    }

    public void setRefid(int refid) {
        this.refid = refid;
    }

    public String getJson() {
        return json;
    }

    public void setJson(String json) {
        this.json = json;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Json)) {
            return false;
        }
        Json other = (Json) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entities.Json[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

**persistance.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="com.mycompany_responseableES_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!--<jta-data-source>java:app/responseablees_working</jta-data-source>-->
        <class>entities.Openanswer</class>
        <class>com.company.responseablees.entities.ResponseHasOpenanswer</class>
        <class>entities.Json</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/evaluationdb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="responseablees"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="responseablees"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <!--         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Code**

```
EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.mycompany_responseableES_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU");
EntityManager em = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
em.getTransaction().begin();
Json json = new Json();

json.setId(1);
json.setRefid(1);
json.setJson("test");

em.persist(json);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Does anyone see a problem with the code I've listed?

Answer (score 0):

There are chances of 'id' field being NULL since it is an Integer. If you use int instead of Integer your issue will get resolved.
You should use Integer only when your column is nullable.
The standard practice is to go with the primitives, unless you're dealing with generics

Read about [autoboxing and unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) in java for more understanding.

Comment: He's using an Integer (as suggested by the Hibernate docs i might add...) because he wants to leave the property null and let the autogeneration strategy do the work.
This is not really an answer to his problem

Comment: Thanks guys, it turns out the id field is auto-incrementing and it is the timestamp that's causing the problem. Honestly, I have built dozens of systems on PHP frameworks, this issue makes no sense to me.